# How can you represent a maze using a graph data structure?

Tags: data-structures, maze

I want to model a maze.

I want to avoid using a matrix in which each cell has four walls (which I could easily do using a two-dimensional array where each cell contains up to four walls) because I don't want the complication of managing the bi-directional relationship with neighboring

I understand that using a graph can potentially help. (I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551575/data-structure-to-represent-a-maze), which suggests using a graph, and I have tried reading up on graph theory a little, but the practical implementation thereof eludes me).

**Can you provide a simple to understand explanation of how to model a maze using a graph?** (The language is not important; I would like to understand the concept).

Comment: In your array (of numbers?) can't you just take "0" to mean "empty" and "1" to mean "wall"?

Comment: Array[n,n] of  array[4] (four walls by cell)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Structure to Represent a Maze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551575/data-structure-to-represent-a-maze)

Comment: @Bret , each cell has four walls. But if I have four walls in each cell, it means I must maintain a bi-directional relationship.

Comment: @Typo, please see my reply to Bret! Also I explained it in the question. I even referred to the question you are suggesting as duplicate and I think it is implicit that my question is different, because I am asking, if graph is the solution, for an example.

Comment: @Typo I have highlighted the portion of the question where I am asking for an example, so you can see it is not duplicate, if you read both questions carefully.

Comment: mydoghasworms You potentially have four walls by cell, as stated by @Bret you can logically represent the existence of each one by value (i.e. 0 = no wall, 1 = wall, 2 = open corridor, etc.). As for the duplicate, you made the same question asking for another answer.

Comment: @Typo: Sigh. OK, I am going to rephrase the question completely. BTW, if each cell has 4 walls, remember that it shares that wall with up to 4 neighbors. If you take down one wall in the cell but not the same wall in the corresponding cell, you end up with a problem, you understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69870/discussion-between-mydoghasworms-and-typo).